# What is the difference between using IOUtils and ImageIO for writing an image file

Tags: java, image, file-io, base64, tiff

I have a tiff image stored as Base64 encoded String in a file. My aim is to create a tiff file out of it. This is what I am doing:

```
String base64encodedTiff = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("C:/tiff-attachment.txt"));    
byte[] imgBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64encodedTiff);
BufferedImage bufImg = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes));   
ImageIO.write(bufImg, "tiff", new File("c:/new-darksouls-imageIO-tiff.tiff"));
```

`ImageIO.write()` is throwing `IllegalArgumentException` because `bufImg` is null. I don't understand what am I doing wrong here.

On the contrary if I use IOUtils to write, it works fine:

```
IOUtils.write(imgBytes, new FileOutputStream("c:/new-darksouls-io-tiff.tiff"));
```

Please help me understand

1. Why ImageIO is throwing exception
2. What is the right API and way for what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

ImageIO would be useful if, for example, you wanted to convert a PNG to a JPEG. Since you don't need to manipulate the image or convert to another format, don't bother with ImageIO.  Just use `IOUtils.write()` to save the TIFF data verbatim.

`ImageIO.read()` is returning a null image because it can't read the TIFF file, probably because TIFF isn't one of the standard ImageIO plugin formats. The standard supported image formats are listed here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html

An additional note -- the code you posted buffers the entire image in memory. If you're concerned about using memory efficiently, consider using some kind of Base64 decoding input stream to perform the decoding on the fly. That might look like this:

```
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:/new-darksouls-io-tiff.tiff");
     FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:/tiff-attachment.txt");
     Base64InputStream decodedIn = new Base64InputStream(in)) {

    IOUtils.copy(decodedIn, out);
}
```

Comment: Changing ImageIO code to use png instead of tiff format still throws same error. Error is thrown right in first line of ImageIO.write() where `bufImg` is null

Comment: The problem is that ImageIO.read() is returning null (because it can't read the TIFF). Changing the output format in ImageIO.write() won't make a lick of difference, because you don't have an image to write!

Comment: Got your point, I should try an example of other supported file format

Comment: Uh, if you use the try-with-resources of Java 7, why use `IOUtils` when you have `Files`?